# Pure Java way to access SPNEGO single sign on in Windows 10

Tags: java, spnego

Is there any pure Java way (no JNA/JNI/Waffle) to access SPNEGO single sign on for a Swing desktop application running on a Windows 10 machine without changing registry keys?

I'm trying to get a token to pass to ADFS to get a SAML token to then pass off to a SAML protected SOAP service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot w/o resorting to native code to SSPI.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that it's now fixed in JDK13+ https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=JDK-6722928.

Update to JDK13+ to resolve this issue.